# Ruby net/ssh(/multi) nested connections

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ssh

I'm attempting to use ruby to connect to mongodb. But first I need to connect to the server hosting mongo.

There is a bastion host that is able to be connected to publicly. The database host is only able to be connected to *through* the bastion.

Here is my code:

```
require 'net/ssh/gateway'
require 'mongo'
include Mongo

ops_host = '<PUBLIC IP/DNS>'
db_host = '<PRIVATE IP>'
port = '27017'
user = 'ubuntu'
key = File.read("<PATHTOKEY>")
gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new( ops_host, user, :key_data => key, :keys_only => TRUE)
gateway.ssh(db_host, user, :key_data => key, :keys_only => TRUE) do |ssh| 
  puts ssh.exec!("hostname") 
  client  = MongoClient.new(db_host, port)
  db   = client.db('<DBNAME>')
  coll = db.collection('profiles')
  puts coll.find().count()
end
```

I'm able to connect to the database host as the `puts ssh.exec!("hostname")` command returns the correct hostname, but I cannot get mongo to connect as I keep recieving `Failed to connect to a master node` errors.

Comment: There's no reason you have to nest these calls, these aren't transactions or something that's intrinsically inter-related. Why not use the multi gem?

Comment: I couldn't find an example or documentation showing that I could connect through each host, one at a time, using that gem. Also the calls are dependent on each other here. You cannot connect to host two without being connected to host one already. The same for host three and two.

Comment: I added an edit to hopefully clarify why I tried to nest the calls.

Comment: Unless you're connecting *through* one host and into the other there's no inter-dependency. Is that what you're doing even though it's not clearly illustrated here? Remember with AWS security groups you can usually simplify your network access and avoid having to repeatedly tunnel.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing. It's setup this way due to some unfortunate requirements for our infrastructure. I added an edit to hopefully clarify that, apologies for the lack of explanation.

Comment: You might want to encapsulate what you're doing in some method that hides the ugly necessity and makes it *seem* like it's just a simple connection.